# Query Result Order mismatch Java sql spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have executed an select query in Oracle Sql, which returns result A in first row, B in second row.  Same query in Java (Spring JDBC) which fetch result in Collections (resultList). In the resultList, the order was reversed. (i.e) B in First Row And A in Second Row.

It was Strange, But to fix this, I have purposely used,`Collections.reverse(resultList)`.(Though, It is a funny idea!) Please suggest me the reason of why the result differ from the sql and Java. Till now there is no problem, when Java return's the result list in some other order, I would be in trouble for sure! 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think you can rely on the order that rows will be returned to Java. Have you put an `ORDER BY` clause on your SQL and it is not working??

Comment: No, I dont have any necessary to put order by in the query.  If I add order by means expected result would be wrong. Till now, it returns in default order only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot avoid using ORDER BY. There's no concept of default order in SQL nor Java. Usually there is an ID primary key which corresponds to insertion order and some JPA use it as default, but still they explicitly say to DB what order use.